# Do kills immediately after victory/defeat count towards your match total?

Tags: overwatch

I've noticed that immediately after the match "Victory"/"Defeat" notification, there is a brief period before the winner screen shows up where you can still get kills on some players. You can confirm the kills with the sound that you hear when you kill players.

**Do these kills count towards your match total?**

For example, if I get 30 kills as Reaper and the "Victory" notification pops up, and before the winner screen appears I complete my 31st kill against a Mercy, does the game record me as having made 30 or 31 kills during the match?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No, they do not. I have tested this myself, as I got killed at the very end of the match after the Victory animation came up, and I was kind of upset because I hadn't died all match (gotta keep that perfect KDA). Then I checked my stats, and I had no deaths for the match. So no, killing or dying after the victory/defeat animation starts does not count towards the stats for the match.

Note: [As @Schism states](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269280/do-kills-immediately-after-victory-defeat-count-towards-your-match-total#comment380278_269284), this is true for all stats. For instance, getting hooks as Roadhog after the match end does not increase your hook percentage or count.

Comment: Just as an addendum: this is true for all stats. For instance, getting hooks as Roadhog after the match end does not increase your hook percentage or count.

Answer (score 27):

A minor caveat to [Dragonrage's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269280/do-kills-immediately-after-victory-defeat-count-towards-your-match-total/269284#269284). On king of the hill maps, kills after a round ends, but not a match end will add towards your total, from testing it myself. However, as Dragonrage has said, kills after a match end will not count towards your total.

Comment: OP explicite asks about the notification. But there is no Notification between the map cahnges of multimap matches.

Comment: @Zaibis still i find that very usefull information

Comment: @Shaeldon: First I downvoted this, but some seconds later I reverted it because I think so too, it IS actually usefull information! I jsut wanted to notify, that thats what OP explicite didn't ask for.

Comment: @Zaibis There is actually a small notification that says "Objective Failed!" if you lost a point and "Objective Captured!" (not sure about this one) whenever you win/lose a round on the KotH maps.

Comment: @cottog: I know and am aware of it. But again: OP explictely asked about `"Victory"/"Defeat"` So if intentional or unintentional, he diferantiated from this kind of event. But don't care that much about it jsut wanted to note it.

Comment: I noticed my damage counting up after a round ended from my turret shooting the other day.